# How can I create a histogram of time stamp deltas?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, kibana

We are storing small documents in ES that represent a sequence of events for an object. Each event has a date/time stamp.  We need to analyze the time between events for all objects over a period of time.

For example, imagine these event json documents:

{ "object":"one", "event":"start", "datetime":"2016-02-09 11:23:01" }

{ "object":"one", "event":"stop", "datetime":"2016-02-09 11:25:01" }

{ "object":"two", "event":"start", "datetime":"2016-01-02 11:23:01" }

{ "object":"two", "event":"stop", "datetime":"2016-01-02 11:24:01" }

What we would want to get out of this is a histogram plotting the two resulting time stamp deltas (from start to stop): 2 minutes / 120 seconds for object one and 1 minute / 60 seconds for object two.

Ultimately we want to monitor the time between start and stop events but it requires that we calculate the time between those events then aggregate them or provide them to the Kibana UI to be aggregated / plotted.  Ideally we would like to feed the results directly to Kibana so we can avoid creating any custom UI.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: I have few quetions. EventA and EventB belong to different document? What do mean by each object identified in query? Can you please specify an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I updated the question to be a little more specific.  Let me know if this explains my question better.

Comment: I don't it is possible with your  current document structure. Can you change your document to have following fields "object", eventStartTime", "eventStoptime"

Comment: No. When the event starts we don't know when it will end. Similarly, when the event ends we don't have the facilities to retrieve the start document.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: We believe that it is possible using Search Aggregations: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html  We just don't know how to leverage them to configure them to accomplish what we need.

Comment: How are you feeding your events into Kibana, via Logstash?

Comment: Kibana talks directly to ES via the REST API. To load our json documents to ES we use the REST API as well. We are open to using other free utilities including logstash if it presents a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're open to use Logstash, there's a way to do it using the [`aggregate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html)

Note that this is a community plugin that needs to be installed first. (i.e. it doesn't ship with Logstash by default)

The main idea of the `aggregate` filter is to merge two "related" log lines. You can configure the plugin so it knows what "related" means. In your case, "related" means that both events must share the same `object` name (i.e. `one` or `two`) and then that the first event has its `event` field with the `start` value and the second event has its `event` field with the `stop` value.

When the filter encounters the `start` event, it stores the `datetime` field of that event in an internal map. When it encounters the `stop` event, it computes the time difference between the two datetimes and stores the duration in seconds in the new `duration` field.

```
input {
    ...
}
filter {
    ...other filters

    if [event] == "start" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{object}"
            code => "map['start'] = event['datetime']"
            map_action => "create"
        }
    } else if [event] == "stop" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{object}"
            code => "map['duration'] = event['datetime'] - map['start']"
            end_of_task => true
            timeout => 120
        }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that you can adjust the `timeout` value (here 120 seconds) to better suit your needs. When the timeout has elapsed and no stop event has happened yet, the existing start event will be ditched.

Comment: Did this work? Is there anything else you need to know?

Comment: Thanks Val. Appreciate the answer. Looks like the solution we're going with. Thanks again.